# Security implications of storing a password in Settings.bundle and getting with CFPreferencesCopyAppValue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, security, sdk, settings.bundle

Apologies for the seeming obviousness of this question, but for whatever reason I haven't been able to find a definitive answer in the Apple documentation about where and how Settings.bundle password info is stored. My question: if I need to store some credentials for an app, and I use a Settings.bundle so that the password is entered into a PSTextFieldSpecifier textfield in Apple's Settings area with IsSecure = YES, and then I access the value from my app using CFPreferencesCopyAppValue, never writing it out to NSUserDefaults and only sending it over the network securely, how secure is that storage and retrieval method when compared to storing and retrieving the password using the keychain in my own app settings?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Consider storing the hash instead of the password. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion -- as I mentioned at the time that I asked this a couple years ago, I just stuck with using the keychain.

Comment: Yep. It's a good option and Apple has certainly improved it since you first asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CFPreferencesCopyAppValue` is just the Core Foundation way of accessing the same information you get when using `NSUserDefaults`. In terms of security, the features are exactly the same. That is, it's not encrypted. It's secure only in the sense that it's obscured. The "correct" answer is to use the keychain.

The counter to that is that many applications use `NSUserDefaults` to store passwords. You could argue that unless the password controls access to information of any value then it's not worth the effort in trying to use the keychain. Which brings me to the second argument in favour of using a secure field in the Settings application: the keychain API is hideous and, in my experience at least, writing error-free code is tricky.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I'm going to stick with the Keychain -- it wasn't clear to me that the Settings info was ending up in the same place as NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You might be interested in using SFHFKeychainUtils: http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/d4298f123a06a91acbe8422ddb6164be3dbcff9e/security. I'm using it for storing passwords and it really simplifies use of the keychain.

Comment: I've found that the Apple sample code that has an implementation of a keychain wrapper for Keychain Services is pretty easy to follow (and then subsequently use the wrapper for your own app keychain management) if you strip out the presentation code from the view controller, which I think is where most of the confusion comes in with that example.

Answer (score 8):

## Don't save a user's password in the settings bundle. 
It isn't secure.

Remember, you don't need to know what the original password is, you need to know if the password the user enters *matches* the original password. The correct way to deal with passwords in iOS is to either

- Use the keychain, as others have mentioned
- Generate a cryptographic one-way hash function using SHA-512 or other encryption and store the resulting hash and salt in `NSUserDefaults`

Of these options, encrypting the password and storing the hash+salt is by far the easiest. Here's what you do to store the password:

1. Grab the password from the user
2. Create a random salt value
3. Create a forward-only hash using SHA-512 and the random salt value
4. Store the resulting hash and salt value in `NSUserDefaults` -- these values can't be used by hackers to determine the original password, so there is no need to store them in a secure place.

Now, when the user enters their password and you have to verify if it's correct, here's what you do:

1. Grab the password from the user
2. Grab the previously saved hash + salt value from `NSUserDefaults`
3. Create a forward-only hash using the same one-way hash function that you used to encrypt the original password -- passing it the attempted password and the salt value from `NSUserDefaults`
4. Compare the resulting hash with the one that was stored in `NSUSerDefaults`. If they are the same, then the user entered the correct password.

Here's the code to generate the salt and the forward-only hash:

```
NSString *FZARandomSalt(void) {
    uint8_t bytes[16] = {0};
    int status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 16, bytes);
    if (status == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Error using randomization services: %s", strerror(errno));
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *salt = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x",
                      bytes[0],  bytes[1],  bytes[2],  bytes[3],
                      bytes[4],  bytes[5],  bytes[6],  bytes[7],
                      bytes[8],  bytes[9],  bytes[10], bytes[11],
                      bytes[12], bytes[13], bytes[14], bytes[15]];
    return salt;
}

NSData *FZAHashPassword(NSString *password, NSString *salt) {
    NSCParameterAssert([salt length] >= 32);
    uint8_t hashBuffer[64] = {0};
    NSString *saltedPassword = [[salt substringToIndex: 32] stringByAppendingString: password];
    const char *passwordBytes = [saltedPassword cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger length = [saltedPassword lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CC_SHA512(passwordBytes, length, hashBuffer);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4999; i++) {
        CC_SHA512(hashBuffer, 64, hashBuffer);
    }
    return [NSData dataWithBytes: hashBuffer length: 64];
}
```

Code for this example was found here: http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2011/04/storing-and-testing-credentials-cocoa-touch-edition/

Answer (score 3):

Keychain on the iPhone is going to be the most secure, unless you're using custom encryption, which is very difficult to do (and export). NSUserDefaults isn't considered secure.