# How to get a unique hash or id from a URL in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my application, I am reading RSS feeds and saving them to a Core Data db using the URL of each specific article as the key. Passing these URLs around the system can be problematic  because they can be lengthy, and I'd like a way to generate a unique identifier to store in the db and just pass that around.

I'd also like it to be reconstructable using the same string so that if I get a duplicate URL, I can generate the identifier from it and simply check Core Data for the identifier.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When most people are talking about hashes, they are generally thinking about one-way hashes like SHA1, SHA2, or MD5. While these are imminently useful, they will not allow you to take a hash and reverse it into its original form. They *will*, however, allow you to do things like compare a user entered password with one they've entered before without ever having to store the actual password -- only the hash.

What you seem to want is string compression or deflation. Luckily, gzip is supported out of the box using the `ASIHTTPRequest` class. Here's some code for using gzip found in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015904/compress-decompress-nsstring-in-objective-c-iphone-using-gzip-or-deflate).

```
NSString *encodedGzippedString = @"GgAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1StfgdKEIgGATJNiQQBDswYjN5pLsHWlHIymrKoHKZVZlXWYWQMztnbz33nvvvffee++997o7nU4n99//P1xmZAFs9s5K2smeIYCqyB8/fnwfPyK+uE6X2SJPiyZ93eaX+TI9Lcuiatvx/wOwYc0HGgAAAA==";
NSData *decodedGzippedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:encodedGzippedString];
NSData* unGzippedJsonData = [ASIHTTPRequest uncompressZippedData:decodedGzippedData];   
NSString* unGzippedJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unGzippedJsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];       
NSLog(@"Result: %@", unGzippedJsonString);
```

There is a very good article that discusses hashing using MD5 here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/hashvalue-object-for-holding-md5-and.html

Using the CommonCrypto library, there are a number of hash algorithms already built in. You can  use the MD5 hasing algorithm like this:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

char input[] = "Some data value.";
char result[16];
CC_MD5(input, strlen(input), result);
```

This will print out the hash in human-readable hex form:

```
printf("MD5 (\"%s\") = %02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x
                       %02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x
                       %02x%02x%02x%02x\n",
    input,
    result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
    result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
    result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
    result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]);
```

If you would like more information on forward-only hashing, I posted some info as well as production-ready code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248575/security-implications-of-storing-a-password-in-settings-bundle-and-getting-with-c/7247210#7247210).

Answer (score 0):

Use SHA1 ([apple implementation of it on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468268/objective-c-sha1)), it will meet all your requirements (re-running it with the same input generates the same output, changing a single character in the input drastically changes the output).

Answer (score 0):

Using a security hashers like MD5 SHA1 or SHA256 leads to a source code which has to change a hasher function each time the algorithm will become obsolete or week. Then corporations which uses automated audit tools will reject the source code with those functions.

So if you need a hasher function for just removing special characters from urls it's better to have a custom hasher than one of those security hashers.